# IE10 and IE11 row height sometimes bigger by 1px

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have done table that all rows should have the same height in normal conditions. It works fine almost everywhere except IE10 and IE11 :( (example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dsb96/7/ )

IE10 and IE11 magically renders additional 1px empty line in some rows (last row in this case), but if I check DOM elements all cells are said to be 17.1px height (in other browsers they are 17px in height).

I assume that this 0.1px difference results that some IE10/11 algorithm finally renders it as additional 1px line in some cell/row.

Can someone explain it to me? or how to fix it?
please see this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dsb96/7/ in IE10/11 and compare it to Chrome or FFX (last row is 1px bigger in height then other rows).

I need solution because in all browsers I have made height of wrapping div to:

```
style="max-height:256px;"
```

and on IE10/11 it has to be

```
style="max-height:257px;"
```

which is very ugly and hard solution.

Comment: A question should contain code for reproducing the problem. Jsfiddle is useful extra, but not enough.

Comment: Jukka K. Korpela - entire code is in jsFiddle, pasting it here will not make any difference at all. Or am I wrong?